# C algorithms for if else functions

Tags: c

I am currently working on a robot and the code below is a boring if else function with a lot else ifs. I am just an absolute beginner.
I was wondering if there is any algorithms I can use instead of this big list of else ifs.
I have googled some stuff but maybe i am googling for the wrong stuff i have not found something usable. If anyone could show me how it could be done to absolutely minimise the amount of else ifs and make it shorter and sweeter that would be of much help to me.

thank you in advance

```
enum s3_states {
    S3_ON,
    S3_OFF

};

typedef enum s3_states switch3_state;

    switch3_state switch3;

(HERE IS MORE BORING BLAH BLAH CODE)
 
//NO BARRIERS AT ALL
            if (state0 == NO_BARRIER && state1 == NO_BARRIER && state2 == NO_BARRIER
                    && state3 == NO_BARRIER && state4 == NO_BARRIER){
                copro_stop();
                copro_setSpeed(23, 23);

                // BARRIER AT SENSOR[0]
            } else if (state0 == BARRIER && state1 == NO_BARRIER && state2 == NO_BARRIER
                            && state3 == NO_BARRIER && state4 == NO_BARRIER) {
                copro_stop();
                copro_setSpeed(9, 15);

                // BARRIER AT SENSOR[0][1]
            } else if (state0 == BARRIER && state1 == BARRIER && state2 == NO_BARRIER
                            && state3 == NO_BARRIER && state4 == NO_BARRIER) {
                copro_stop();
                copro_setSpeed(5, 15);

                // BARRIER AT SENSOR[0][1][2][4]
            } else if (state0 == BARRIER && state1 == BARRIER && state2 == BARRIER
                            && state3 == NO_BARRIER && state4 == BARRIER) {
                copro_stop();
                copro_setSpeed(-5, 15);

                // BARRIER AT SENSOR[0][1][2]
            } else if (state0 == BARRIER && state1 == BARRIER && state2 == BARRIER
                            && state3 == NO_BARRIER && state4 == NO_BARRIER) {
                copro_stop();
                copro_setSpeed(-1, 15);


                // BARRIER AT SENSOR[0][1][2][3]
            } else if (state0 == BARRIER && state1 == BARRIER && state2 == BARRIER
                            && state3 == BARRIER && state4 == NO_BARRIER) {
                copro_stop();
                copro_setSpeed(-17, 15);

                // BARRIER AT SENSOR[4]
            }else if (state0 == NO_BARRIER && state1 == NO_BARRIER && state2 == NO_BARRIER
                        && state3 == NO_BARRIER && state4 == BARRIER){
                copro_stop();
                copro_setSpeed(15, 8);

                // BARRIER AT SENSOR[4][3]
            } else if (state0 == NO_BARRIER && state1 == NO_BARRIER && state2 == NO_BARRIER
                            && state3 == BARRIER && state4 == BARRIER) {
                copro_stop();
                copro_setSpeed(15, 3);

                // BARRIER AT SENSOR[4][3][2]
            } else if (state0 == NO_BARRIER && state1 == NO_BARRIER && state2 == BARRIER
                            && state3 == BARRIER && state4 == BARRIER) {
                copro_stop();
                copro_setSpeed(15, -1);

                // BARRIER AT SENSOR[4][3][2][0]
            } else if (state0 == BARRIER && state1 == NO_BARRIER && state2 == BARRIER
                            && state3 == BARRIER && state4 == BARRIER) {
                copro_stop();
                copro_setSpeed(15, -5);

                // BARRIER AT SENSOR [4][3][2][1]
            } else if (state0 == NO_BARRIER && state1 == BARRIER && state2 == BARRIER
                            && state3 == BARRIER && state4 == BARRIER) {
                copro_stop();
                copro_setSpeed(15, -17);

                // BARRIER AT SENSOR [0][4]
            } else if (state0 == BARRIER && state1 == NO_BARRIER && state2 == NO_BARRIER
                            && state3 == NO_BARRIER && state4 == BARRIER) {
                //copro_stop();
                copro_setSpeed(15, 15);

                // BARRIER AT SENSOR [1][2][3]
            } else if (state0 == NO_BARRIER && state1 == BARRIER && state2 == BARRIER
                            && state3 == BARRIER && state4 == NO_BARRIER) {

                if (((copro_distance[0] / 256 > 25) + (copro_distance[1] / 256 > 25)) >
                ((copro_distance[4] / 256 > 25) + (copro_distance[3] / 256 > 25))){

                    copro_setSpeed(40, -40);
                } else {
                    copro_setSpeed(-40,40);
                }



            } else if (state0 == BARRIER && state1 == BARRIER && state2 == NO_BARRIER
                            && state3 == BARRIER && state4 == BARRIER) {
                copro_stop();
                copro_setSpeed(12, 12);

        /**
            } else if (state0 == BARRIER && state2 == BARRIER && state4 == BARRIER) {;
                copro_stop();
                copro_setSpeed(-15, -15);
        **/
                // BARRIER AT ALL SENSORS
            } else if (state0 == BARRIER && state1 == BARRIER && state2 == BARRIER
                    && state3 == BARRIER && state4 == BARRIER) {

                if (((copro_distance[0] / 256 > 25) + (copro_distance[1] / 256 > 25)) >
                ((copro_distance[4] / 256 > 25) + (copro_distance[3] / 256 > 25))){

                    copro_setSpeed(40, -40);
                } else {
                    copro_setSpeed(-40,40);
                }
```

Comment: It would help to understand what this code was intended to accomplish because otherwise, we have to figure that out before we can write sensible code to accomplish the same thing. I suspect the solution will consist of two chunks of code, one to fill out an array with the correct strategy for each combination of states and another to just access the correct array element and execute the strategy stored there.

Comment: If there are only 2 values for each state for each then you can use one bit of the same variable for each state. You've then got the entire system state in a single variable and can use `switch` with a series of `case` statements that cover all the valid conditions.

Comment: Another way would be to deal with `state0` first. `if(state0 == BARRIER) { /* do stuff/* } else { /* do other stuff */ }`. Within each of those two code blocks you then examine `state1` and so on. That would at least give more readable code.

Comment: Turn `state 4`, `state 3`, `state 2` and `state 1` into a 4-bit value (e.g. `state = state_4<<3 | state_3<<2 | state_2<<1 | state_1` and then `switch (state) { case 0:, ... case 15: }`

Answer (score 1):

Change your code step by step.

Step 1: Convert the pattern from 5 values to one number.

```
int number0 = (state0 == barrier ? 16 : 0);
int number1= (state1== barrier ? 8 : 0);
… 
int number4= (state4 == barrier ? 1 : 0);
Int number = number0+number1+…+number4;
```

So now you have a number from 0 to 31. Change each if you “if (number == x)” …

Four variables:

```
Bool stop = false;
Bool setSpeed = false;
Int speed1 = 0;
Int speed2 = 0;
```

Replace calls to stopcopro with stop = true. Replace calls to copro_setSpeed with setSpeed = true; speed1 = first param, speed2 = 2nd param. After the if, add “if ( stop) … if setSpeed ( …)”

Replace the if with a case statement.

Make a table with the speed values. Take the speed values from the table. Now you can combine lots of cases into one. Look for more ways to simplify your code.